# While loop is not inserting data properly when it executes more than one time

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

While loop working accurate first time but when it executes second or more than one time it just save single column of row and don't pick the field by name because I tried to alert field value.
Here is my code

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $vnumber=$_POST['number'];
    $ex_rate=$_POST['xrate'];
    $acc_code=$_POST['code1'];

    $y = mysql_query("SELECT * from accounts where CODE='$acc_code'");
    $j = mysql_fetch_array($y);

    $acc_name=$j['NAME'];
    $entry_date=$_POST['edate'];
    $voucher_date=$_POST['vdate'];

    $va=$_POST['hfield']-1;

    $counter=1;

    while ($counter<=$va) {
        $scode=$_POST['acccode'.$counter];

        echo '<script>alert('.$scode.')</script>';

        $yy = mysql_query("SELECT * from accounts where CODE='$scode'") or mysql_error();
        $jjj = mysql_fetch_array($yy);
        $sname=$jjj['NAME'];

        echo '<script>alert("do it")</script>';
        echo '<script>alert('.$sname.')</script>';

        $lamount=$_POST['local-amount'.$counter];

        echo '<script>alert('.$lamount.')</script>';

        $usd=$_POST['usd'.$counter];
        $remark=$_POST['comment'.$counter];
        $serial=$counter;

        $insert2=mysql_query("insert into sender(SA_CODE,SA_NAME,L_AMOUNT,USD,REMARK,SR_NBR)value('$scode','$sname','$lamount','$usd','$remark','$serial')") or mysql_error();
        $counter++;
        echo '<script>alert('.$counter.')</script>';
    }//while

    $insert=mysql_query("insert into reciever(ENTRY_DATE,VOUCHER_DATE,EX_RATE,CODE,ACC_NAME,NUM) values('$entry_date','$voucher_date','$ex_rate','$acc_code','$acc_name','$vnumber')") or mysql_error();
    echo('<script>alert("Submitted")</script>');
    printf("<script>location.href='voucher3.php'</script>");
}
```

and Here is how this behavior with Database when more the one row inserted 
[PHPMyAdmin Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WnpH8.png)

Comment: You shouldn't use any mysql_*-functions. They have been deprecated since php 5.5 and completely removed in php 7.0

Comment: Did you check if your POST data are correct?

Comment: I'm using PHP 5.5 @Manish

Comment: Yes @nospor. Everything is fine

Comment: try outputting `$insert2`. currently if `mysql_query` fails (ignoring the deprecated library) you then store the error then....nothing because shortly after you enter the next iteration and the data in `$insert2` is replaced. `$insert2` may have an error message for you

Comment: I tried to show mysql_error() with $insert2 but no error is happening @Memor-X

Comment: You are also wide open to SQL injection attacks, which is a more important reason to switch to PDO, prepared statements and bound parameters right now!

Comment: @Zain ok. another method you could do is rather than executing the query each iteration of your loop generate a single query. so before your loop you have `$insert2="";` then inside your loop you go `$insert2.="[your query]"`. then outside your loop run the query

Comment: @Memor-X I'm looking for an other solution it's not working in this scenario

Comment: Thanks to all , I got my error it was because of misplace Form starting Tag. But i don't know why was it working for first row

Answer (score 0):

```
$scode=$_POST['acccode'.$counter];
```

I guess u must me adding acccode & counter to get scode
**scode = acccode + counter**
but the value of acccode you get from the post is string, hence it does not give u desired integer.
As all the values over HTTP are string or binaries.
so you have to convert the value to integer first and then add it.

```
(int)$_POST['scode']
```

Comment: Thanks, I got my error it was because of misplace Form starting Tag. But i don't know why was it working for first row.